# Помогите написать скрипт который меняет раскладку на противоположную

Tags: python

Нужен код что бы если у нас стояла русская раскладка ставилась английская и наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

В окнах можно попробовать сделать вот так:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from pyautogui import hotkey
import ctypes 

def get_layout():
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4190419':
        return 'ru'
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4090409':
        return 'en'

if get_layout() == 'en':
    hotkey('alt', 'shift')
```

Альтернативный способ:

```
import ctypes 

def get_layout():
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    pf = getattr(u, "GetKeyboardLayout")
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4190419':
        return 'ru'
    if hex(pf(0)) == '0x4090409':
        return 'en'


def change_layout():
    u = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
    u.SendMessageW(0xFFFF, 0x50, 0, 0)  # Сообщение WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST

if get_layout() == 'en':
    change_layout()
```

Comment: нужно без нажатий на клавишу, а просто что бы при вызове менялся

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте альтернативный способ.